# Does changing `wal_keep_segments` require a restart?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a need to increase `wal_keep_segments` on our master server. Can I do that on the fly or does it require a restart?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For checking the variable's context, you can execute the following query:

```
SELECT name, context FROM pg_settings WHERE name = '<variable name';
```

In the case of `wal_keep_segments`, the context is `sighup` which means that only requires a server reload. You can use `pg_ctl reload` from the shell prompt or `select pg_reload_conf()` from psql or database client.

In the latest version, there are 7 types of context. `internal` context means that only can be modified at compilation time, `postmaster` means that a service restart is needed, the others are more session/backend specific.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the docs [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/config-setting.html#CONFIG-SETTING-CONFIGURATION-FILE) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-replication.html) modifying this parameter does not require a server restart. Otherwise it would be noted as `This parameter can only be set at server start`

`pg_ctl reload` will send a `SIGHUP` to the running processes and reload the setting. This should be run for any server that has the setting modified.